# Get keys from yaml file using bash

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I have a yaml file like this one:

```
env:
 firstVar: true
 secondVar: 20
 aa_thirdVar: 'hello'
 aa_fourthVar: false
```

and I need to get the keys under the `env` key except for the keys with `aa_` prefix as a bash array in order to use the array in a bash script. I need to do this using standard Linux tools like `sed`, `awk` etc. without external dependencies. How can accomplish that?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this answer is more general. I explored available questions/answers before posting mine.

Comment: what would be the resulting array? `([firstvar]="true" [secondVar]="20")`?

Comment: The resulting array is supposed to contain only keys without the `aa_` prefix like ARR=(firstVar, secondVar).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is produce `key=value` pairs.

You can use `ruby` with the built in yaml parser:

```
ruby -r yaml -e 'data=YAML.load($<.read)
data["env"].
    select{|k,v| k.to_s.match(/^(?!aa)/)}.
    each{|k,v| puts "#{k}=#{v}"}
' file
```

Or, more fragile, you could use this `awk`:

```
awk '
/^env:/{con=$1; next}
$1~/aa_/{next}
con=="env" 
{sub(/:$/,"",$1); print $1 "=" $2}' file
```

Either of those prints:

```
firstVar=true
secondVar=20
```

Now have a Bash loop that will add key=value type pairs to an associative array `aa` like so:

```
declare -A aa
while IFS="=" read -r k v; do
    echo "$k $v"
    aa["$k"]="$v"
done < <(ruby -r yaml -e 'data=YAML.load($<.read)
data["env"].
    select{|k,v| k.to_s.match(/^(?!aa)/)}.
    each{|k,v| puts "#{k}=#{v}"}
' file)
```

Result:

```
declare -p aa
```

Prints:

```
declare -A aa=([firstVar]="true" [secondVar]="20" )
```

Answer (score 0):

i use yq that is wrapper for jq tool
https://github.com/kislyuk/yq